# Can I enter the US with a Green Card about to expire?

Tags: usa, residency, visa-expiration

My Green Card expired in April, however in February I applied for renewal, and it was extended through November. I am travelling overseas and returning on November 28th. Since I have not yet received the new Green Card, could I have problems entering the US with a Green Card that is about to expire two days later?

Comment: As far as I can tell, a green card is either unexpired, and valid for entry, or expired. There is no almost-expired. The danger is that you will hit some problem, such as being too ill to travel or a major airline glitch, that delays your return. Can you have a friend or relative receive your mail while you are traveling, pull the replacement green card, and send it to you?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan   Thank you, I was asking because for passports this isn't true, and sometimes expiring passports are an issue.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan there's a provision for a waiver if the returning resident can show that the reason for not having a valid green card was beyond her control.  Of course, it would be better not to have to rely on that, but if there are major delays, the possibility would exist.

Comment: @phoog Yes, especially in this case of a green card that was extended because of the incredible slowness of green card renewals. Last time I renewed mine, the new card arrived a few weeks before the end of the extension.

Comment: Apparently it has gotten worse. From https://egov.uscis.gov/cris/ptAllFormsAverage.do waiting days for 2017 are 309 vs. 183 in 2016: Application to Replace Permanent Resident Card 10-year renewal 309 183 163 168

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just realised this question had no answer. Since I returned with no problem, I am going to post as an answer my own experience.

Yes, returning caused no problem, my green card was still valid (albeit for just a couple more days) and I came in with no issue. A month later I finally received the replacement.

Comment: Did you raise the question of the impending expiration with the immigration officer, and, if so, how did the officer react?

Comment: @phoog The immigration officer did not ask any question, and I did not raise the issue. Everything went as usual.